# Format result from SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning SQL with Oracle. I have query that shows 3 columms from a table called `people`: `show last name`, `first name` . I want to display another column that indicates that if there is phone number to show it and if it is null to show it as `XXX-XXX-XXXX`.  So far my query shows the information but not in the format that i want.

```
Select last_name, first_name, phone_number AS phone_Num from people
```

Results:

```
LAST_NAME        FIRST_NAME       PHONE_NUM
---------------- ---------------- ------------
Doe              Fred
Hanes            Tina             123-587-9087
Douglas          Tim
McCarthy         Bob              212-098-9876
```

Desired:

```
LAST_NAME        FIRST_NAME       PHONE_NUM    HAS_PHONE_NUM
---------------- ---------------- ------------ -------------
Doe              Fred                           XXX-XXX-XXXX
Hanes            Tina             123-587-9087  123-587-9087
Douglas          Tim                            XXX-XXX-XXXX
McCarthy         Bob              212-098-9876  212-098-9876
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [COALESCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) function:

Try this:

```
 Select last_name, first_name, phone_number AS phone_Num,
 coalesce(phone_number, 'XXX-XXX-XXXX') as HAS_PHONE_NUM from people
```

Or use [NVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) :

```
 Select last_name, first_name, phone_number AS phone_Num,
 nvl(phone_number, 'XXX-XXX-XXXX') as HAS_PHONE_NUM from people
```

`COALESCE` is a part of ANSI-92 standard and `NVL` is Oracle specific.

Comment: I don't see any `NULL` values in the `phone_number` column

Answer (score 0):

Use `Case Statement`

```
SELECT last_name, 
       first_name, 
       phone_number AS phone_Num, 
       CASE 
         WHEN phone_number = '' THEN 'XXX-XXX-XXXX' --or Lenght(phone_number) = 0
         ELSE phone_number 
       END          AS HAS_PHONE_NUM 
FROM   people
```